# Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to add a Kotlin Multiplatform Module as part of an Android project I am building. In the library, my top level `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

Then my app level build.gradle.kts looks like this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 31
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 31
    }
}
```

Back in my Android project I am including the file in the settings.gradle like this:

```
include ':SampleModule'
project(':SampleModule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../SampleModule')
```

Then in my build.gradle like this:

```
implementation project(path: ':SampleModule')
```

Unfortunately though, I keep getting the same frustrating error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :SampleModule.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'custombuild' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :SampleModule.
```

Any idea why this might be happening?